# How to manage MS Dynamics 365 CRM Portal custom codes?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, portal, source-code-protection, dynamics-crm-portals

I would like to know how to auto manage **portal's *custom code*** just like in TFS/VSTS?

At present ,I am using XRMToolbox to manage ,push or pull portal's code into CRM Instance but disadvantage is code **checkin and checkout.**

Can anyone help me in this to manage a code with auto pull and push option into CRM instance with checkin ,checkout options?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the XRMToolbox plugin doesn't support it yet.

> Ref: https://github.com/MscrmTools/MscrmTools.PortalCodeEditor/issues/13

But there is no stopping you from creating your own pipeline - at the end of the day portal code is just bunch of Crm entities. Part of Crm SDK is configuration migration tool - last version is here:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.ConfigurationMigration.Wpf

So the idea is:

1) Get this tool

2) Define entities you want to backup & create schema xml file for them. I think you'd want adx_webpage, adx_webfile, adx_pagetemplate (and all attributes from them)

3) Export data using this schema - this exports them to .zip package that contains simple structure (schema file and data file); so you can unzip it and store in your git branch (pull)

4) For push zip this file and again use configuration migration tool to import the data

This gives you also an opportunity to have separate dev version of portal code and production version of portal code (which is always a good thing).

Comment: Also i devlope the tool which helps to  publish JS codes into CRM instance ! Thanks Much

Answer (score 2):

Portals code is made up of configuration changes to a solution (which can be extracted as xml) and data (records such as web pages, web roles etc.)

There are several tools available to help you source control both.

[xrm-ci-framework](https://github.com/WaelHamze/xrm-ci-framework) provides automation tools to extract your CRM solution as xml, and then source control it. You can do this locally or in the cloud with Azure DevOps or other.

[msbuild-xrm-sourcecontrol](https://github.com/Capgemini/msbuild-xrm-sourcecontrol) is similar. It integrates into Visual Studio to help you extract CRM customisations locally. It also has a partner project [xrm-datamigration](https://github.com/Capgemini/xrm-datamigration) which helps you extract data from CRM, version control it and deploy it to other environments in your release pipeline. Both have documentation on the GitHub pages I've linked; [this blog post](https://medium.com/capgemini-dynamics-365-team/msbuild-xrm-sourcecontrol-finally-version-control-support-for-dynamics-2a59c3f0a5ce) is informative too.